# How to ensure a script's Awake() gets executed before the rest in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that I need to become `Awake()` before any of the other scripts in the scene. Besides making every other script call `OnEnable()` or `Start()` instead of `Awake()`, is there perhaps a simpler method to ensuring that one script gets called first every time this scene is loaded?

As a more fundamental question: what determines which script's `Awake()` function gets called first in a scene?

Comment: @Ruzihm Looks like the accepted answer there does. Thanks!